# Is there any easier way to set integer for string characters?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, int, charat

I am making converter which converts random string to numbers fancy way. But I was wondering is there easier way to do this:

```js
package codec;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public final class Codec extends JFrame { 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
         String x = "qwertyuiopasdfghjkl";
           int a = x.charAt(1);    
           int b = x.charAt(2);
           int c = x.charAt(3);
           int d = x.charAt(4);
           int e = x.charAt(5);
           int f = x.charAt(6);
           int g = x.charAt(7);
           int h = x.charAt(8);
           int i = x.charAt(9);
           int j = x.charAt(10);
           int k = x.charAt(11);
           int l = x.charAt(12);
           int m = x.charAt(13);
           int n = x.charAt(14);
           int o = x.charAt(15);
           int p = x.charAt(16);
           int q = x.charAt(17);
           int r = x.charAt(18);
           System.out.println(a*b+c+d*e+f+g*h+i+j*k+l*m+n*o+p+q*r);
 }
}
```

It gives me "81782", and I can simply change numbers and calculation.
I haven't written java much, so I am really beginner.
Is it plausible to do this with loop like:

```js
for (int i = 1; i < x.length() ; i++){
//code  
}
```

Comment: Unless you define the operation `System.out.println(a*b+c+d*e+f+g*h+i+j*k+l*m+n*o+p+q*r);`  precisely. Even on getting the value using the loop all you would end up doing possibly is saving the values in an `int` array.

Comment: Possible if the expression is `a*b+c + d*e+f + g*h+i + j*k+l + m*n+o + p*q+r`. That would get the expression in the form of `Σ x*y+z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help you. Also, please note, that strings starts from index 0, not 1. So, your 'a' is symbol 'w'.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "qwertyuiopasdfghjkl";
    Map<Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<>();
    char c = 'a';
    for (int i = 1; i < x.length(); i++) {
        charMap.put(c++, (int) x.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(charMap.get('a') * charMap.get('b')
                       + charMap.get('c')
                       + charMap.get('d') * charMap.get('e')
                       + charMap.get('f')
                       + charMap.get('g') * charMap.get('h')
                       + charMap.get('i')
                       + charMap.get('j') * charMap.get('k')
                       + charMap.get('l') * charMap.get('m')
                       + charMap.get('n') * charMap.get('o')
                       + charMap.get('p')
                       + charMap.get('q') * charMap.get('r'));
}
```

Comment: Your method works but don't you think this could be at a certain point far to resource consuming? I've measured it for the simple example: 
>81782
>Pomper's method: 192137 nanoseconds
>81782
>Solorad's method: 596116 nanoseconds
        
Clearly I don't know how exhaustive @Pomper want to use it.

Comment: This helps me a lot making code like I was looking for. And as @Jodn said that your method is more resource consuming, it doesn't matter much because I am just testing stuff at this point.

Comment: I showed clear  method with for loop as it was asked in question. Unforunetly, sometimes it is needed to choose between perfomance and easiness of read.

Comment: @Soloard I agree with you ;).
PS: Pomper, just in case you didn't know you can iterate trough a string's chars with: for(char e: x.toCharArray()){  } ... I Just want to leave this here. Have fun with testing your stuff ;)

Answer (score -1):

here is the code to use loop

```
String afd = "234567890";
    int sum=0;
    for(int ij=0;ij<afd.length();ij+=2)
    {
        sum = sum + (afd.charAt(ij)*afd.charAt(ij+1));
    }
       System.out.println(sum);
```

hope my code helps you in this regard.Happy coding

Comment: That sums all variables together, the idea is that I could use advanced calculations between numbers to get always unique result. Like sin(a)*sqrt(b-c)... between all variables. When the result is unique, I could plausibly convert numbers into words or letters. So it would be fancy crypt, a bit like Minecraft seed generator.

Comment: if you want to use 3 numbers at once in an operatiom the n increment ij+=3 and change internal operation you want to perform it works